# Why does sklearn's best_estimator_ not return all of the variables (XGBoost)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have a problem with best_estimator_ in XGBoost, which is that it doesn't return all of the variables I need, and just returns three dots at the end. Here's what it looks like:

```
clf.best_estimator_
XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', callbacks=None,
              colsample_bylevel=1, colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=0.4,
              early_stopping_rounds=None, enable_categorical=False,
              eval_metric=None, gamma=0.25, gpu_id=0, grow_policy='depthwise',
              importance_type='gain', interaction_constraints='',
              learning_rate=0.125, max_bin=256, max_cat_to_onehot=4,
              max_delta_step=0, max_depth=5, max_leaves=0, min_child_weight=9,
              missing=nan, monotone_constraints='()', n_estimators=800,
              n_jobs=-1, num_parallel_tree=1, predictor='auto', random_state=0,
              reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, ...)
```

Do you guys have any idea why that's happening? Here's the code I used to train the model for context:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
import xgboost

classifier=xgboost.XGBClassifier(tree_method='gpu_hist', booster='gbtree', importance_type='gain')

params={
    "base_score":[0.5], 
    "colsample_bylevel":[1],
    "colsample_bynode":[1], 
    "colsample_bytree":[0.4], 
    "gamma":[0.25], 
    "gpu_id":[0],
    "learning_rate":[0.125], 
    "max_delta_step":[0], 
    "max_depth":[5],
    "min_child_weight":[9],
    "n_estimators":[800], 
    "n_jobs":[-1], 
    "num_parallel_tree":[1], 
    "random_state":[0],
    "reg_alpha":[0], 
    "reg_lambda":[1], 
    "scale_pos_weight":[10,11,12,13], 
    "subsample":[1], 
    "validate_parameters":[1], 
    "verbosity":[0]}

clf=RandomizedSearchCV(classifier,param_distributions=params,n_iter=6,scoring='accuracy',cv=6,verbose=3)
clf.fit(X,y)
```

Comment: does this help `clf.best_estimator_.get_params()`

Comment: @Chris oh yeah, it does :) but I want them to be organized as they are when I do clf.best_estimator_, so this is only partially a solution

Comment: From scikit-learn v0.23, the display configuration has to be set before like this:

`from sklearn import set_config`
`set_config(print_changed_only=False)`.